# "Read-only file system error" on Samba share, alternative share with identical options working (Linux client)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, samba, readonly

I'm experiencing a very strange problem which I've been trying to solve in the past few days and I already tried various methods of resolution to which I will get to in a moment.

My home network consists of a micro server (Ubuntu Linux Server 17.04, kernel 4.10.0-26-generic on x86_64, CLI only) and several Windows and Linux clients. My goal is to set up a Samba share with read-only guest access and read-write access for myself (Linux Mint 18.1, kernel 4.4.0-81-generic).

In my smb.conf, there are two identical shares, media and temp (the later is for bug fixing purposes):

```
[media]
comment = smb share
path = /media
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = no
write list = ap

[temp]
comment = smb share
path = /temp
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = no
write list = ap
```

/media and /temp both are set to **chmod -R 775** and **chown -R ap:ap**.

Now the strange thing is that I can access both shares from my Linux client as ap but I only have write access on [temp]. When I try to create a folder or delete a file on [media], I get a "Read-only file system" error. I also don't have any problems writing when I log onto my server (as root user ap) using SSL.

It might also be of interest that I'm mounting three different internal hard drives to /media/*. Their fstab entries look like this:

```
UUID=954d122e-ef13-4248-acb3-5c95fb44d2ad /media/misc ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=d213c725-a715-40f3-8278-de890fad1168 /media/cinema ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=6469b3d0-bdb5-4b0c-8559-b9d26f69b332 /media/series ext4 defaults 0 0
```

The following possible solutions didn't work:

- Setting chmod to 777, setting chown back to root:root
- fscking all partitions, including the system partition
- Playing around with my smb.conf (trying out options like valid users, read list, create mask)
- Adding ap as a Samba user
- Trying to mount the share with *mount -t cifs -o username=ap //server /mntpoint* (and trying out options like rw,uid,gid,domain,forceuid,forcegid)
- remounting my internal hard disks with the rw option

I guess that I could switch to NFS but I'm still wondering if I missed something very obvious or what further steps I could take to solve this problem.